# How to hook to an object without bending the mesh in the wrong direction?

Tags: armature, physics, hook-modifier

I have a question about trying to hook object ends. The idea is to link an air hose to the valve of a dive tank on one end, and have it link to the mouthpiece on the other end. Both work fine when tilting an armature in one direction, however the end that attaches to the tank valve stretches in both directions so if I move the neck to right the hose moves correctly, but if I move the neck to the left it bends the hose at the hook point which is very unrealistic behavior. The mouthpiece is already locked to the applicable bone as is the dive vest on which the tank is mounted as part of the overall object for that. Is there any way to anchor the end of the hose that connects to the tank valve so that it doesn't bend in the wrong direction when the armature's neck moves?

Comment: Can you provide more details including some images if possible. It would also be useful if you could share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to your question into the field on that page and it will then appear in your question.

Comment: [Here you go.](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZRXDYNn3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest that you use a Bezier curve for the hose instead? because the hose in your blend seems to be a regular mesh.

> **You can create a Bezier curve (Add > Curve > Bezier) that consists of preferably two points to make it easy. You can hook those two points to the two separate objects/bones/vertexes you want to connect.** *(in this case, the two objects would be the Valve and the Mount Piece)*

This way, the hose will bend, deform and rotate properly.
If you have more points, you ultimately have more control. For example, adding a third point somewhere in the middle of the two points and hooking that to a new object allows you to control the middle area of the house separately.

I've experimented with it and the results I got seem like what you're looking for after checking out the blend you've provided. ***see below***

**v Resting (not rotated or moved) v**
[image]

**v Rotated and moved it v**

[image]

**v EXAMPLE: New point added and hooked to another new object v**

[image]

The two points stay in their position and rotate accordingly. Hope this helped :)

Here's the file for you to play around with: [image]

Comment: That's certainly the conventional way. I usually put an empty where I want each end of the hose to be attached, parent the emptys to the objects with Keep Transform, and then hook each end of the Bezier Curve to the emptys. Not sure why you want the hooked empty in the centre unless you need to control the position of the hose exactly.

Comment: @JohnEason The hooked centre is just an example if you want more points or control. Apologies if my answer is confusing and please do edit my answer if needed

Comment: Fair enough. You can also keyframe it to stop it intersecting objects if necessary.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help @JeffreyDavis :)